# What is exactly the difference between method and function in Python language?

Tags: python, function, methods

I do not know the difference between Method and function in Python Language, for example, the difference between len() and string.upper(), I mean len and.upper
I would be delighted if someone could help me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Methods are an entity pertaining to the world of object-oriented programming  and are defined on objects, functions are independent of objects.

See
[What's the difference between a method and a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/whats-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function)